# include scripts in laravel ,Laravel generate wrong url

Tags: javascript, laravel, url

I am trying to include a js files i use

```
<script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/custom.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.easing.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('contactform/contactform.js')}}"></script>
```

//these folders in puplic folders,this works when i have a url like
 http://localhost:8888/htdocs/graduation/public/coursepage
but if i have a url like this
http://localhost:8888/htdocs/graduation/public/coursepage/CMPE224-fall-2017
**it gives this errors**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
css/font-awesome.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
css/imagehover.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
css/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
laravel generate this url http://localhost:8888/htdocs/graduation/public/coursepage/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

considering that the folder in coursepage but it is not ,it is in puplic and i do not have coursepage folder how i can get the correct url

Comment: Have you tried with `src="{{url('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"` and what is your app url that you have configured as base url

Comment: yes i tried src="{{url('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}" it gives the same error and it is generate a wrong url

Comment: when you put `{{asset('js/custom.js')}}` what you get as full url on your browser's console. can you post your full URL that you get

Comment: i get http://localhost:8888/htdocs/graduation/public/coursepage/css/imagehover.min.css http://localhost:8888/htdocs/graduation/public/coursepage/css/style.css

Comment: `/coursepage/` what is this, a route if yes please set your base url correctly on your env and app.config file. or for quick solution put `/` infront of all like `<script src="{{asset('/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>` and also if this not works then  put like this `<script src="{{asset('../js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>`.....what is your base url on .env file though

Comment: yes coursepage is a route i tried ur solutions, unfortunately, it did not work. APP_URL=http://localhost in .env

Comment: change your app url to `http://localhost:8888/htdocs/graduation/public/` and lets see

Comment: same problem GET http://localhost:8888/htdocs/graduation/public/coursepage/css/imagehover.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED

Comment: it works just if i create a folder named ''coursepage" and put the linked folder inside it

Comment: yeah but again will be problem with different route other than `coursepage`......anyways do your webserver configured as allowOverride all? apache or other server?

Comment: yes <Directory "C:/MAMP/bin/MAMP/">
 Options Indexes MultiViews ExecCGI
 AllowOverride All
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from localhost
 Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that page has the same scripts loaded in? You could do a `@extends('master')` and have a `@stack('js')` in the master file. Then in your file all you'd do it

```
@push('js')
<script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/custom.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.easing.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('contactform/contactform.js')}}"></script>
@endpush
```

Comment: Or, if you're using these scripts everywhere, you could specify them once in a 'scripts.blade.php' file and just include it in your master.

Comment: i have them in different file and i include them in main.blade.php @include('partials._head')
@include('partials._nav')
@yield('content')
@include('partials._footer')
@include('partials._scripts')and i extend it in each page

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem , the problem was in the _head file

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Candal|Alegreya+Sans">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/font-awesome.min.css')}}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/imagehover.min.css')}}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">
```

i did not use the asset method here when i add it it works